# Refresh InnerText of Div using setInterval

Tags: javascript

I am trying to constantly update a DIV on our landing page to display the number people waiting in our live chat system queue.

The following code works fine in Chrome and updates every 5 seconds however in IE it obtains the value the first time it runs but then doesn't update.

```
<head>
<script>
setInterval(function() {

var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("support_session_count");
    txt=x[7].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    document.getElementById("Sessions_Waiting").innerText = txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://my.server.com/command.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}, 5000); 
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Does the interval function get called every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I added an Alert(txt) to check this....

It fires every 5 seconds, in Chrome it shows the new value, in IE it stays the original value

Comment: so in IE `txt=x[7].childNodes[0].nodeValue;` does produce new text every time, just not updating the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be that IE caches the result. This is a common problem. You can either force the no-cache in your server, or append a unique postfix.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://my.server.com/command.xml?nocache"+(new Date().getTime()),true);
```

Comment: I think I wasted almost a year of my time trying to fix issues that was related to browser cache.